# jQuery Sortable - No Effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have existing tabs in my page and was looking at a way to reorder them, I used [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sP3UZ/2760/) as a guide but nothing happens - no errors and no sign of sortable working when dragging a tab.

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(function() {

        // reorder thread tabs
        jQuery("#crm_nav_tab_names").sortable({
            revert: true
        });

    });

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="crm_nav_tab_names" class="tab_names charlie_small">
    <div id="thread_0" class="ui-state-default"><a href="#">1</a></div>
    <div id="thread_1" class="ui-state-default"><a href="#">2</a></div>
    <div id="thread_2" class="ui-state-default"><a href="#">3</a></div>
</div>
```

My version seems to work in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KbyCu/

Even this fiddle with some of my css seems to be working - http://jsfiddle.net/KbyCu/2/ - but yet there is nothing happening on my page.

I realise there's not much that can be done if it's working in a fiddle and not in the actual page someone might be aware of some kind of common 'gotchas'.

For more info on the page, I'm using Rub on Rails 2 with Ruby 1.8.7 to dynamically produce the tabs but none of that should matter as it's generating the markup above.

Comment: It worked for me , drag the div horizontally

Comment: If you inspect your page and delete all elements from the inspector, will it work then? If yes then you know where to look at. Also try to comment out your js and call it from console once you remove all other elements and only keep what you have posted. If you manage to make it work this way, then you'll have a method to debug the problem.

Comment: thanks, found the problem just after asking the question, hate when that happens. Problem was the tab partial (Rails version of include) was using the same id for this set of tabs as the main navigation (duplicate id's) so it was probably confusing the jQuery, changed the id and it worked.